# Are there Monodevelop add-ins that assist with refactoring?

Tags: add-in, monodevelop

What  refactoring tools similar to Visual Studio / DevExpress / Resharper are available for the Linux environment?  Specifically I'm interested in the global renaming and method generation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

MonoDevelop 2.2 supports several refactoring operations out of the box:

- Rename Refactoring with Preview
- Resolve Namespace
- Extract Method Declare Local Variable
- Integrate Temporary Variable
- Introduce Constant Move Type to Own
- File Remove Unused Usings Sort Usings
- Create/Remove Backing Store Inline
- Rename Generation of interface and virtual method overrides Generation
  of constructors

Comment: MonoDevelop 3.0 has had a massive amount of work for refactoring and code analysis. It really is rather cool now!

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't seem to be any, but you can quickly compose your own:
http://monodevelop.com/Developers/Articles/Refactoring